# Golang compiler in yocto embedded system

Tags: go, yocto

On my Yocto embedded system, for development purpose, I need GO compiler. I have added recipe go to my image, which added go compiler to system. But when I try to run project, I got bunch of errors like following:

```
cmd/updater/main.go:8:2: package text/tabwriter is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/text/tabwriter)
../go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.3.0/unix/syscall_linux.go:18:2: package time is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/time)
../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godbus/dbus/v5@v5.0.3-0.20190910164622-6eb4cf171088/variant_lexer.go:6:2: package unicode is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/unicode)
../go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/term@v0.3.0/terminal.go:13:2: package unicode/utf8 is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/unicode/utf8)
../go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.3.0/unix/affinity_linux.go:11:2: package unsafe is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/unsafe)
```

Common solutions mentioned on internet are:

- Set environmental variables GOROOT and GOPATH.

  - If I print out `go env` command, my GOROOT='/usr/lib/go' and GOPATH='/home/root/go'. If I use `echo $GOROOT`, variable is empty. If I set it by `export GOROOT='/usr/lib/go'`, there is no difference, error persists.
- Use `go mod tidy`

  - There were some downloading, when I tried this first time. I have also tried `go mod download` and `go mod vendor`. But error persists.

I'm pretty new to GO language, but I didn't have this issue on my desktop.

Comment: 1) Never set `GOROOT` by hand; just ignore the (dirt-old) HOWTOs suggesting that ;-) 2) Can you go to `/usr/lib/go/src` and verify there exists a directory named `text` with a directory named `tabwriter` in it? Presently it looks like `GOROOT` is left overridden and screws up searching for standard (stdlib) packages. Or the installation itself is somehow screwed up so that the toolchain is installed but the source code of the stdlib packages is missing.